# Can't install Themes in Wordpress 4.1 (cURL failure)

Tags: wordpress, curl, themes

In Wordpress V4.1 I am trying to install a new Theme. Wordpress throws the following error message:

> Download failed. error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

I think it is the cURL transport which is failing. I installed the "Core Control" plugin and tested the curl functionality. This test tells me, that cURL and PHP-Stream is working.

I now found out that SSH2 is not available on the server.

Is it possible to use Wordpress without SSH2?

Comment: can you install themes or plugins using ftp?

Comment: Yes, ftp is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch the installations and updates to using FTP rather than the built in downloader. Because of the way the server is setup, some of my sites automatically use it unless overridden.

You can force wp to use FTP for installing/updating plugins and themes by adding this line into the wp-config.php file:
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');

Comment: After some searching I found the "Core Control" plugin, which makes it possible to set up the method you suggested using the Wordpress backend. Thank you for this hint.